# Custom URL rewrite with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am trying to create the SEO friendly URL:
http:///foto/linse2-at/linse2-at-schloss-altenhof/2618

for this one:
http:///?fotograf=linse2-at?gallery=linse2-at-schloss-altenhof&img=2618

For my logic, this code should work:

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
    "foto/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([0-9]{1,})/?",
    "index.php?fotograf=$matches[1]&gallery=$matches[2]&img=$matches[2]",
    "top");
```

But the the rule generated is (dump of global $wp_rewrite):

[foto/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([0-9]{1,})/?] => index.php?fotograf=&gallery=&img=

..which does not work.

It seems that the "$matches[1]" are missing.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: what are `fotograf`, `gallery`, and `img`? Are those registered query vars? Rewrite rules have to result in a successful main query that loads some type of WordPress object- a page, a post, an archive.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Maybe this is why the rewrite rule does not work. "fotograf" mapps to a custom content type. "gallery" and "img" are  not directly a "WordPress object" they are only HTTP-GET parameters, which are used on the fotograf-page: single-fotograf.php. Is this really a the reason why the rewrite rule does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the rewrite-rules manually as follows worked for me:

```
 function gallery_rewriterules( $wp_rewrite ) {

  $new_rules = array( "hochzeitsfotografen/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([0-9] {1,})/?" => "index.php?fotograf=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)."& gallery=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)."&img=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index(3));
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;  
  }
  add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules','gallery_rewriterules');
```